# Consumir servicio POST Angular 4

Tags: angular, servicio

Estoy desarrollando una webapp en la que necesito consumir un servicio POST utilizando para ello Angular4. La configuración de las cabeceras y demás está todo bien pero a la hora de realizar la llamada al servicio me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el 
> recurso remoto en http://82.165.15.254/geolocalizador_eventos/ws/v4/obtener_eventos.php
> (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').
> ```

He estado buscando y todo indica que debo añadir dicha cabecera en la respuesta del servicio; pero mi pregunta es **¿por qué sin añadir esa cabecera en cualquier testeador online de REST services me da la respuesta de manera correcta?**

Comment: Lo que te pasa es algo normal: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery Verifica que en el servidor permita el acceso desde tu dominio.

Comment: Estás usuando angular-cli? porque en ese caso podés configurar un proxy al momento de hacer ng-serve y eso puede resolver tu problema.

Comment: Como se da el caso de que stoy utilizando angular-cli, ¿cómo podría configurar el proxy? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En el servicio rest debe poner `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` donde se dice que para el puerto 4200 no va a poner restricciones de consumo.

Además se debe de configurar estas lineas en el *build*

```
bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service-cors'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
```

Más información es este link:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/